# How to find the first and second maximum number?

Tags: excel, worksheet-function

I am trying to find first highest number and second highest number in excel. What shall i do for that. I did not find the right formula.

Note: I have already used the large and max formula.

```
=LARGE(E4:E9;1)
```

edit: guys I know if i write 2 instead of 1 i will get the result but i have to click the mouse to see all result.

Answer (score 30):

If you want the second highest number you can use

`=LARGE(E4:E9;2)`

although that doesn't account for duplicates so you could get the same result as the Max

If you want the largest number that is smaller than the maximum number you can use this version

`=LARGE(E4:E9;COUNTIF(E4:E9;MAX(E4:E9))+1)`

Comment: I marked it up for the correct answer, but the second method is very good.

Comment: @James L. whether you use ; or , depends on regional settings, I use comma too but I used ; in the answer here because that was the format used in the question....but perhaps that's why it didn't work?!

Answer (score 2):

OK I found it.

=LARGE($E$4:$E$9;A12)

=large(array, k)

Array  Required. The array or range of data for which you want to determine the k-th largest value.

K Required. The position (from the largest) in the array or cell range of data to return.

Comment: I wrote 1 instead of choose the cell. now if i click the mouse i see the first highest and second highest number. so from the largest to second largest and third largest. i do not have to write eveythime 1 2 or 3.