# Excel - Index Match where max value (return multiple results and remove duplicates)

Tags: excel, indexing, max, match

I have an index match formula like so:

```
=INDEX('Opp Data'!H:H, MATCH(MAX('Opp Data'!I:I), 'Opp Data'!I:I, 0))
```

This looks up my data on Opp Data sheet:

```
Column H          Column I
Client A          £100
Client B          £50
Client C          £0
```

the formula then returns my the client name with the corresponding largest spend:

i.e. `Client A`

Next, i need to be able to produce multiple results, so i need to repeat this formula down several rows on my spreadsheet and each time return the next largest value (without showing duplicates). For example:

```
Client A
Client B
etc.
```

Please can someone show me how to do this? Thanks in advance

Comment: Use "LARGE" instead of "MAX" to get the next biggest value. [Here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20011864/how-to-find-the-first-and-second-maximum-number) is how you can avoid duplicates.

Comment: @ctumturk thank you for your suggestion. If i use large, how would i also be able to add other match criteria's in please?

Comment: I posted my solution down below

Answer (score 0):

here is my solution;

```
=INDEX($A$2:$A$5;MATCH(LARGE($B$2:$B$5;COUNTIF($B$2:$B$5;MAX($B$2:$B$5))+COUNTA($B$2:B4)-1);$B$2:$B$5;0))
```

and the screenshot;

[image]

Comment: Thanks, but what if i also had a date in column C like 01/01/2016 and i needed to add a matching criteria for this to say if matches date?

Comment: can you set an example table with the expected outcome?