# VBA: find second largest value

Tags: vba, excel

I have the following problem: I try to filter a date column (A) in a worksheet (HISTORICALS) to return the highest and second highest date value. Currently, there is dates ranging from the 25th to the 31st of December in this column. Unfortunately, below formula (using the Large function) returns the 31st two times (and not the 30th and 31st as intended).

```
Sub Select_Last_Two_Days()

    With Worksheets("HISTORICALS")
        Highest_Max = Format(WorksheetFunction.Large(Worksheets("HISTORICALS").Range("A:A"), 1), "Short Date")
        Second_Highest_Max = Format(WorksheetFunction.Large(Worksheets("HISTORICALS").Range("A:A"), 2), "Short Date")
        Debug.Print Highest_Max, Second_Highest_Max
    End With

End Sub
```

The column has approx. 2000 rows, with dates occuring multiple times. So ideally I would want to filter for distinct values and then return the two highest dates. Any idea how I can do that?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20011864/how-to-find-the-first-and-second-maximum-number#20011896

Comment: Hey Axel, this won't work since the column A has over 2000 entries, so selecting LARGE(Range, 2) will just give me the second highest value, which is still the 31st. I first need a formula to filter out the distinct dates in that column and then select the two highest. Basically like the SELECT DISTINCT function in SQL..

Comment: Can you use an array?

Comment: @calicationoflife You should take the second part from answer linked by Axel. Translate this formula `=LARGE(E4:E9;COUNTIF(E4:E9;MAX(E4:E9))+1)` into VBA and your case and you're good.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Simply translate Barry Houdinis answer from [How to find the first and second maximum number?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20011864/how-to-find-the-first-and-second-maximum-number#20011896) to VBA:

```
Sub Select_Last_Two_Days()

    With Worksheets("HISTORICALS")
        Highest_Max = Format(WorksheetFunction.Max(.Range("A:A")), "Short Date")
        Second_Highest_Max = Format(WorksheetFunction.Large(.Range("A:A"), WorksheetFunction.CountIf(.Range("A:A"), WorksheetFunction.Max(.Range("A:A"))) + 1), "Short Date")
        Debug.Print Highest_Max, Second_Highest_Max
    End With

End Sub
```

Answer (score 1):

The recommendations given in the comments are probably the simplest and least amount of code way to do things but here is another sugggestion:

```
Sub test()

Dim wb As Workbook
Dim ws As Worksheet

Set wb = ThisWorkbook
Set ws = wb.Worksheets("HISTORICALS")

Dim lastRow As Long

lastRow = ws.Cells(ws.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row

Dim loopArr()

loopArr = ws.Range("A1:A" & lastRow).Value

Dim maxVal As Date

maxVal = Application.WorksheetFunction.Large(ws.Range("A1:A" & lastRow), 1)

Dim i As Long
Dim secondVal As Date

   For i = UBound(loopArr, 1) To LBound(loopArr, 1) Step -1

        If loopArr(i, 1) < maxVal Then
          secondVal = loopArr(i, 1)
          Exit For
        End If
   Next i

End Sub
```